# Which scallops change their sex from male to female?

Tags: marine-biology, sex, sexual-dimorphism

Tonight it occurred to me to look up what scallops are like when they are alive (beyond their culinary role) and it blew my mind. This post regards one detail about which I was unable to find specific information: apparently certain species are known to start off as male and then change to female later in their lives. Which species in particular are known to do this?

*I am new to this SE community so please let me know if there's anything I should refine about this (my first) post.*

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. As you're looking for advice.... Always link to whatever you've found so far. For example, link to the document where you read about scallops gender change in life.

Comment: This type of sex determination system is called [sequential hermaphroditism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_hermaphroditism). Clown fish are a classical example of sequential hermaphrodites.